# Disable the use of multiple rows in FlowLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, flowlayoutpanel, flowlayout

I can't find how to disable the automatic creation of rows in [`Flowlayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) when re-sizing the container. It's mentioned in the docs that:

> If the horizontal space in the container is too small to put all the components 
>   in one row, the FlowLayout class uses multiple rows.

How can I disable this feature?

Comment: As an aside, what ***should*** happen instead when 'the container is too small to put all the components in one row'?  Ignore (don't show) the components that are last, ignore the components that are first, show scroll-bars, ..?

Comment: What i want is to re-size the components to fit the size of the container, and hide some of them when it become too small.

Comment: What components (JButtons, JLabels etc.) are they?  What are they supposed to display when they are resized smaller than can display the content?  I don't think that resizing components is a practical approach, BTW.

Comment: JLabels with icons. So ignore some components will a good solution?

Comment: *"ignore some components will a good solution?"* No, I'd offer a scroll-bar unless the images are pure fluff, then I wouldn't include them at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use FlowLayout. Instead have you tried BoxLayout, organized as BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS.

Comment: Exactly, by using the BoxLayout in a Container with a flowLayout i can get what i want, the reaction of the BoxLayout and the alignment of the Flow one.